# Quartz JDBC - Spring Boot getting much slower after restart

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I implemented Quartz with JDBC storage (using rdb from awds). To shut down the app, I shutdown the spring app, remove all tables of quartz in DB, then recreate them, start the spring app again. However, every single time after restarting like that, Quartz is extremely slower than the first run.
I guess it's because resources are still in use because after waiting a few hours, Quartz is fast again.
Any idea about this problem? It's also great if you guys can show me the proper way to reset everything.

Comment: Just wondering, why do you remove tables after stopping the spring application and recreate it?

Comment: @Saheb just for testing, we only run the test for 10 mins, after 10mins any uncompleted job will be terminated